# Oracle error while saving form with selenium

Tags: python, oracle, selenium, automated-tests

I use python selenium for testing a form, and if I want to save it I get this error message back:

```
Error during save operation! ORA-01403: no data found
```

But if I save the form manually everything goes fine. In both cases the form is saved. Can you help me with this? How can I fix it, not to get this error message?

Thanks.

Comment: any errors in javascript console in browser?

Comment: nope, nothing  :/

Comment: Check network tabs

Comment: I can't do that during the test, only when I do it manually, but the error only occurs with selenium

Comment: Launch the browser with selenium, put a breakpoint on save form and then launch the network tab manually in browser. Continue the script and see what is sent from the form. And then compare that with manual submission also

Comment: I don't use selenium ide, and as far as I know if I have my python code in Notepad++ with selenium webdriver I can't add breakpoint anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you are seeing `Error during save operation! ORA-01403: no data found` seems to be a purely a timing issue.

**Possible Cause** (from Oracle Book) :

> [This page](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?8309-ORA-01403-no-data-found-how-do-you-solve-this) mentions, in a host language program, all records have been fetched. The return code from the fetch was +4, indicating that all records have been returned from the SQL query.

**Details** :

> `ORA-01403` in association with the SELECT INTO clause with Oracle Database. [This page](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01403_no_data_found.htm) clearly mentions the following:
>   SELECT INTO clauses are standard SQL queries which pull a row or set of columns from a database, and put the retrieved data into variables which have been predefined.
>
> If the SELECT INTO statement doesn't return at least on e row, ORA-01403 is thrown.

**A possible solution is** :

> To avoid ORA-01403, the PL/SQL has to contain exceptions , otherwise the query will offer to values to the defined variable.  If the exceptions are not defined properly, you will encounter ORA-01403, and your situation may worsen each time you attempt to access the particular variable. Creating an exception in which only one row can be retrieved would allow the code to appropriately handle the exception without receiving the ORA-01403 error.

**Selenium**:

> I think a possible solution may be to induce `WebDriverWait` after filling up the text and also some `WebDriverWait` before clicking on `Save` button.

Comment: Yes, thats what I thought as well but I already have plenty of Webdriver wait-s there...and I don't really know what should I wait for